# on occassions git diff shows all changes between branch point of main (using gitt diff main and rebased)

Tags: git, git-diff

On occasions my team gets all changes between the point of creating the feat branch and main, even after rebasing.. we fail to see a pattern for this.

Let's say we have this timeline flow

- main (sha: 000000) => create new feat/test_function
- person x does changes on main (sha: 000001)
- I do changes on feat/test_function (sha: 000002)

I do

> git diff main

Now I see the diffs (000001 and 000002) (as if I created 000001).

We figured we try rebase (still the same).

Trying

> git rebase main -i strategy-option theirs

And squashing our commits into a single one commit seems to resolve this, but we wonder why this sometimes happens.

Comment: When your issue happens, check `git log --graph --oneline main <your branch>`, and check if your branch is based on the latest version of `main`. One consistent way to see the modifications on your branch only (even when `main` gets updated) is : `git diff main...HEAD` (3 dots, not a typo)

Answer (score 0):

If `main` evolves -- for example, if you run `git pull` from your local `main` branch on a regular basis -- the modifications that land in `main` and that aren't part of your branch will appear in `git diff main your/branch`.

One way to see the changes that were made on `my/branch` only and ignore changes that were made on `main` is :

```
git diff main...your/branch

# if your/branch is the current branch, you can also run :
git diff main...HEAD
git diff main...
```

---

The 3-dots notation for git diff is documented [in the beginning of `git help diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-emgitdiffemltoptionsgtltcommitgtltcommitgt--ltpathgt82308203-1) :

> `git diff [<options>] <commit>...<commit> [--] [<path>…​]`
>
> This form is to view the changes on the branch containing and up to the second `<commit>`, starting at a common ancestor of both `<commit>`. `git diff A...B` is equivalent to `git diff $(git merge-base A B) B`. You can omit any one of `<commit>`, which has the same effect as using `HEAD` instead.

The result is the same as what you would see in the "diff" tab of Pull requests or Merge requests on services such as Github, Gitlab, Azure Devops, etc ...

Comment: This is true, and makes sense but we only get these diffs sometimes, would it not make sense that 

git diff main

after a rebase only shows the diff between my branch commits and main and does not include the main commits?

Comment: @CisumInas: if you run `git rebase main`, you replay the commits specific to your branch on top of `main`, which is one way to integrate the changes from `main`. When you run `git diff main` after that, you only see the changes on you branch.

Comment: You can observe that the "changes in main" are reversed : you will see lines "added" to main showing up as "deleted" in `git diff main your/branch` -- and vice versa: lines "deleted" from main will show up as "added".

Comment: As I said in a comment to your question : use `git log --oneline --graph main your/branch` to have a clearer view of what gets compared. You can run it before and after `git rebase`.